# why should i increase the trust level of assemblies in my system?

Tags: asp.net

in my project I have added the reference of ajax tool kit. when i am running it is giving error like increase the trust level. What is that, why should we increase the trust level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you put an assembly in the GAC, it is meant to run in medium trust on an ASP.NET web server, in order to improve security and minimize the possibility of your website getting hacked.

To upgrade the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit, you only need to copy over the AJAX Control Toolkit assembly into the \bin directory (no other code changes required).

ASP.NET AJAX 1.0 itself needs to be registered in the GAC of the server you are running.  There is a trick to avoid registering it in the GAC which is to run the application with full trust, and then place it in the \bin directory of the application.  This isn't recommended because it means the assembly can't be updated/serviced by Microsoft - but it will work.

Note that most hosters run applications under medium trust - in which case this approach won't work.  But if you have full control of the server you can do it.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/25/updated-asp-net-ajax-control-toolkit-release-and-new-asp-net-ajax-videos-articles.aspx